# Не могу найти проигрыватель rtmp

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, flash, потоки-данных, rtmp

Есть устройства, они транслируют на мой сервер видеопоток по протоколу rtmp, у меня все замечательно работает, но есть один момент. Мне нужно выводить на сайте, живые трансляции. Проигрыватели которые я ставил jwplayer и ему подобные, videojs и тд - видео все,все хорошо показывают, но стоит мне зайти на сайт например с мобильного телефона, как все катится к чертям, не один из мне попавшихся плееров не грузят видео поток, либо не отображаются или отображаются с ошибками.
Существует ли нормальный проигрыватель на сайт, с поддержкой live rtmp? Если да подскажите.

Comment: а погуглить? вот на флеше http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.5.0/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html там же демка есть что бы потестить

Comment: @perfect спасибо, а ты пробовал с мобильника, то что нагуглил? Я пробовал этот плеер - шляпа.

Comment: я мобильной разработкой не занимаюсь. но предположил что adobe flash player должен работать везде одинаково. может мобильное устройство на котором тестиш глючит? к примеру оно просто не выдерживает мощный видеопоток.

Comment: @perfect про adobe flash player вы конкретно не правы, если бы все было как вы говорите, было бы прекрасно быть разработчиком=))) К сожалению   adobe flash player  по дефолту далеко не на каждом устройстве есть, и даже не в этом проблема....

Comment: а голый html до 5 версии вообще с анимацией не работал. а флеш самая первая такая технология и самая популярная. по дефолту ее существовать не должно потому что это дополнение. а в чем тогда проблема? в вашем вопросе про мобильный телефон написано и меня естественно удивляет какой такой телефон не поддерживает хотя бы оперу мобайл.

Comment: @perfect я с вами не согласен, но не буду откланяться от исхода проблемы, то что вы скинули ссылку не работает на телефонах семейства android по крайне мере 5 версии по дефолту. У меня Meizu 3, а так же не работает на lumia 640 те на windows phone 8.1. Так же как и то что вы скинули, не работает и jwplayer, videojs, Flowplayer и многие другие.

Comment: rtmp не работает на мобилах, расходитесь

Answer (score 1):

Нет такого плеера. Rtmp это говно мамонта. Его стоит использовать как промежуточное решение, но как конечное уже давно устарело. Rtmp в WEB приложения играется через flash, задержку накапливает.